# Using Komodo Editor 8.5, How can I create a project that has a linked page for javascript functions as part of a larger project?

Tags: javascript, html, web, project, komodo

Sorry for the basic question, I'm a beginner with some basic knowledge of html, css and beginning with javascript that I'm learning for developing my own web project.  I'm trying to create a project with a separate page for functions to keep the page cleaner and see all the functions in one place.  I'm watching videos as part of an online course. However, the lectures use Visual Studio in which you can drag and drop the files so that the source link is already coded. If there's an equivalent feature, let me know please.

I know that you are supposed to link the `<script type = "text/javascript" script src = XXXX.js>`  However, whenever I copy the file path, it still doesn't come up.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the text that links your JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/file.js"></script>
```

Even though with HTML5 you might not need quotes around your attribute content, it's safe to put them in for older browsers. Don't put a space between the attribute name and the equals sign, or between the attribute content and the equals sign. There shouldn't be a `script` in the middle of your tag (you put one before `src`). Make sure the [file path is relative to your HTML file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths) as well.